# Need help getting the right query on repository laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4, repository

I need to fetch the categorie name from the images to the ImagesRepository

So far in ImagesRepository i got:

```
public function latest($limit = 8)
    {
        return $this->image->whereNotNull('poster')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->limit($limit)
        ->get();
    }
```

I tried using leftJoin but it didnt work:

```
 public function latest($limit = 8)
        {
            return $this->image->whereNotNull('poster')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->limit($limit)
            ->leftJoin('category', 'id', '=', 'category_id')
            ->get();
        }
```

Now i need to get the id from the Category Table that matches the category_id so i can get the right url link to the post.

Cause my result right now is :

**localhost/test/1/name-1**

and i need to get:

**localhost/test/1-flowers/name-1**

OK so after carefully looking at laravel documentation i figured it out the solution since they are already relationships in the eloquent all i have to do is call the table by simple adding a line...

```
public function latest($limit = 8)
    {
        return $this->image->whereNotNull('poster')
        ->with('category')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->limit($limit)
        ->get();
    }
```

Comment: So is your problem related to the repository, the routing or the category relationships?

Comment: is not the route is just the query the relationships are already made by images been part of the same namespace and eloquent just need to get the right query that's all, i tried join but it didn't work.

Comment: You should maybe post more code so we can see what you're trying to do.